# Laravel Backpack table field columns (json-array) validation rules not working

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-7, laravel-backpack

I'm using BackpackForLaravel and I have a `table` type field in my code:

```
$this->crud->addField([
    'label'           => 'Contact persons',
    'name'            => 'contact',
    'type'            => 'table',
    'entity_singular' => 'contact',
    'columns'         => [
        'person' => 'Person',
        'email'  => 'Email',
        'number' => 'Phone number',
        'desc'   => 'Description',
    ],
    'attributes'        => [
        'required' => true
    ],
    'max'               => 5,
    'min'               => 1,
    'wrapper'           => [
        'class' => 'form-group col-12'
    ],
    'tab' => 'Contact data',
]);
```

The CRUD work fine, but when I add validation, something is not working properly.

My `ClientRequest.php` class has:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'cif'                            => "required|spanish_tax_number|unique:clients,cif,{$this->cif},cif",
            'name'                           => 'required|min:3|max:255',
            'address'                        => 'required|json',
            'weekly_rest'                    => 'nullable|array',
            'description'                    => 'nullable|max:255',
            'leaving_date'                   => 'nullable|date',
            'leaving_date'                   => 'nullable|date',
            'image'                          => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png',
            'contact'                        => 'required|array',
            'contact.*.person'               => 'required|email'
        ];
    }
```

`contact` field validation works well, but when I tried to use `contact.*.person` to validate all `array` fields named `person`, nothing happens.

I used the function `prepareForValidation` to modify field `json` format to `array` format:

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
    {
        $this->merge([
            'contact' => json_decode($this->input('contact'))
        ]);
    }
```

If I dump input data, I can view that function `prepareForValidation` is working well, but the validation isn't doing nothing.

I read about array validation here:

- https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/1582
- https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#validating-arrays

I do this, and works (do the validation in `store`/`update` controller function):

- https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/607#issuecomment-293729520

But, I would like to do this without this vervosity, coding all in `ClientRequest` class.

I think that I'm doing well, but not works.

What am I doing wrong in `ClientRequest`?

---

**EDIT**

Output of `request()->all()` inside `rules()`, function of `ClientRequest.php`

```
array:15 [▼
  "_token" => "DGnGIZwertI6kupXwYgHr8as5MVbD2sPRlmbGJrK"
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "http_referrer" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/client?active=1"
  "id" => "21"
  "cif" => "123456789F"
  "name" => "Paco Porras SL"
  "address" => "Useful address, 1"
  "weekly_rest" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "2"
    1 => "3"
    2 => "4"
  ]
  "description" => "qweqwe"
  "discharge_date" => "2020-07-08"
  "leaving_date" => null
  "image" => null
  "contact" => "[{"person":"123123123","email":"sss.ssstyytrytr","number":"qwewqe","desc":"qweq"},{"person":"123123123","email":"123123","number":"123123","desc":"123213"}]"
  "current_tab" => "datos-de-empresa"
  "save_action" => "save_and_edit"
]
```

Output after `prepareForValidation`:

```
array:15 [▼
  "_token" => "DGnGIZwertI6kupXwYgHr8as5MVbD2sPRlmbGJrK"
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "http_referrer" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/client?active=1"
  "id" => "21"
  "cif" => "123456789F"
  "name" => "Paco Porras SL"
  "address" => "Useful address, 1"
  "weekly_rest" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "2"
    1 => "3"
    2 => "4"
  ]
  "description" => "qweqwe"
  "discharge_date" => "2020-07-08"
  "leaving_date" => null
  "image" => null
  "contact" => array:2 [▼
    0 => {#1557 ▼
      +"person": "123123123"
      +"email": "sss.ssstyytrytr"
      +"number": "qwewqe"
      +"desc": "qweq"
    }
    1 => {#1556 ▼
      +"person": "123123123"
      +"email": "123123"
      +"number": "123123"
      +"desc": "123213"
    }
  ]
  "current_tab" => "datos-de-empresa"
  "save_action" => "save_and_edit"
]
```

**EDIT 2**

I do this in store/update function of `ClientController.php`:

```
$validate = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'contact'                          => 'required|array',
            'contact.person'                   => 'required|string',
            "contact.*.person"                 => 'required|string',
        ]);

dd($validate->messages());
```

And the output is:

```
Illuminate\Support\MessageBag {#1520 ▼
  #messages: array:2 [▼
    "contact" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "El campo contact debe ser un array."
    ]
    "contact.person" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "El campo contact.person es obligatorio."
    ]
  ]
  #format: ":message"
}
```

Something isn't working well because `'contact.*.person'` is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
'contact' => json_decode($this->input('contact'))
```

on

```
'contact' => json_decode($this->input('contact'), true)
```

and leave your old rules

Comment: Thanks for response, but that not works because validation expects a 'contact.person' field name a never exists. I tried too. Any other option that you know?

Comment: @Sakrow Can you send an array that you send to validation? `dd($request->all())`

Comment: @RamizKongulov Hello, I edited the question adding more information. I hope it's useful to you. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Sakrow `contact.*.person` - This is the correct expression if you have a multidimensional array.
Could you send a validation error?
`$validate = Validator::make($request->all(), ADD_RULE); dd($validate->messages())`

Comment: @RamizKongulov I updated it with the output. Something isn't working because `'contact.*.person'` not appear

Comment: @Sakrow "El campo contact debe ser un array." - From this error, you can understand that contact is not an array. Check the sent date again.

Comment: @Sakrow I changed the answer

Comment: @RamizKongulov yeah! Now is working well, the error is to not use the `assoc` parameter in `json_decode` function. If you don't use it, the array is `stdClass` inside. Thanks for helping me to view the error.

Comment: @Sakrow Yes, I only recently noticed this in code. Happy to help!